# Bcrypt, password and hashedpasword don't match. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: node.js, postman, bcrypt

I encountered a weird problem in here. My input password and hashedpassword don't match somehow. I need a second opinion here.

**User Model File, User.js**

```
UserSchema.pre("save",function(next) {
    
    if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        next();
    }
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) next(err);
        bcrypt.hash("this.password", salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) next(err);
            this.password = hash;
            next();
        });
        
    });
})
```

**inputHelper.js**

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")


const validateUserInput = (email, password) => {
    return email && password;
}
const comparePassword = (password, hashedPassword) => {

   return bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword);       
}
module.exports = {              
    comparePassword,
    validateUserInput
};
```

**Auth.js**

```
const {
    validateUserInput, 
    comparePassword
} = require("../helpers/input/inputHelper");

const login = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {

    const {email, password} = req.body;

    if (!validateUserInput(email, password)) {                          
        
        return next(new CustomError("Please check your inputs", 400));
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({email}).select("+password");

    if (comparePassword(password, user.password)) {

        sendJwtToClient(user,res,200);   // Success
        
    }else{
        
        return next(new CustomError("Please check your credentials", 400));  // Fail
    }
    
});
```

I am using postman to test my login function.

https://prnt.sc/JhQKxj50qYxt

MongoDb registered user

https://prnt.sc/LIsvFCcMK6jl

As you can see on the Cookies part, I am creating a access token but somehow, my hashedpassword and password don't match. Maybe there is a problem on hashing process? I can provide more information to answer your questions.

**FIXED**

Solution is to change "this.password" to this.password without using " ". It was a typo error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your User model, `"this.password"` is a string -- did you mean `this.password?

Comment: This was the problem! You saved me, thanks! I edited, from "this.password" to this.password. Typos are bad omen.